# How to call function in a widget from a Floating Action Button Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, floating-action-button

is quite simple

The background of the managed by a widget called HomeBackground. So there I just want to some properties from the Floating action Button.

Here is de Background:

```
class _IconsBackground extends StatefulWidget {


final bool isLoading;
  final IconData firstIcon;
  const _IconsBackground({required this.firstIcon, required this.isLoading});

  @override
  State<_IconsBackground> createState() => _IconsBackgroundState();
}

class _IconsBackgroundState extends State<_IconsBackground> {
  bool isDarkMode = false;
  Color iconsColor = AppTheme.primary;
  List<Color> background = [
    const Color.fromARGB(255, 234, 231, 231),
    Colors.grey
  ];

  swtichTheme() {
    isDarkMode = !isDarkMode;
    if (isDarkMode) {
      iconsColor = Colors.white;
      background = const [
        Color.fromARGB(255, 64, 64, 64),
        Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)
      ];
    } else {
      iconsColor = AppTheme.primary;
      background = [const Color.fromARGB(255, 234, 231, 231), Colors.grey];
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container( // more things
```

So the switchTheme() method should be called from the floating action Button in the Home Screen:

```
    class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final BlogsProvider provider = Provider.of<BlogsProvider>(context);
    
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: const BlogAppBar(),
        floatingActionButton: const **_UserActionsButton()**,
        body: **HomeBackground**(
            firstIcon: Icons.chat,
            isLoading: false,
            child: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: () async {
                provider.getBlogs();
              },
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                child: Column(
                  children: _loadBlogs(provider),
                ),
              ),
            )));
  
    }

    List<BlogCard> _loadBlogs(BlogsProvider provider) {
        List<Blog> blogsSorted = provider.blogs;
        blogsSorted.sort((a, b) => a.created.compareTo(b.created));
        return blogsSorted.reversed.toList().map((e) => BlogCard(blog: e)).toList();
      }
    }
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two simple ways to do it:

1. Set a StatefulWidget higher up in the tree, for example in your HomeScreen, and then pass the method to change the theme and the current theme to the FloatingActionButton. Additionally, send the current theme to the Background widget.
2. You are already using the Provider package, create an additional provider for the theme and store the current theme and the method to change it within that provider.

Comment: Great teacher, the 2 option was the best approach and the solution. Thanks!